# Use of iphone default alert tone

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I'm try to build a messaging apps, with push notification applied. I wish to apply user defined notification tone, like whatsApps does. I notice whatsApps is using IOS default sound system, and i google around, there is a method to get system sound, by accessing **"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds"**. However, i notice the list returned is not same as the list in system **"Setting->sound"**.

Here is my question

1) how am i possible to get all the sound file, is good with the naming same as IOS setting.
2) If i wanted to apply those sound in push notification, do all the .caf file need to include in my apps bundle?
3) is yes, is it possible i able to download it over internet?(i've google a lot and found no luck) or any way to convert/export it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to set server side payload json like following:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert = "Hello World";
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

**sound = default;** that alert tone apply default one

For second question yes you have to put all sound file in to your apps bundle.

And do not forget to set this following code in to your Appdelegate class when you `registerForRemoteNotificationType` :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/iphonesounds/iPhoneOriginalSystemSounds_WAV.zip?attredirects=1) it is link for iPhone sound files list.

Comment: Thank for fast response. The download is awesome! but i afraid it is not full list. i try to implement the list like whatsApps do,but i unable to get all the file. I notice most of the whatsApps implemented tone is available in IOS system tone, but i unable to obtain it.

Comment: I suggest to you that  use **sound = default;** normally we are used default one.

Comment: sound = default is use the sound set in system right? but i wish to provide more customisation to user, as they can set the notification sound for this particular apps. that why i need the whole list. Anyway, will accept this answer. Thank dude.